# Sample all but first elements from flux in project reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

In project reactor flux there is a sample method [Flux#sample java doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sample-java.time.Duration-). It changes flux so that it emits events only at the ends of specified periods.

Is it possible to tweak this behaviour and achieve this : on first element - emit it instantly , start sampling with delay from 2nd up to the end. Basically I want to exclude first (and only first) element from sampling so that it is emmited without initial wait.

Would it be possible to achieve using built-in operators ? If not then does anybody have an idea how to approach this problem ?

Here is a simplest example of what I want to achieve :

```
Flux<String> inputFlux = Flux.just("first", "second", "third").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(400));
Flux<String> transformed = /*do some magic with input flux*/;

StepVerifier.create(transformed)
    .expectNext("first")//first should always be emmited instantly
    //second arrives 400ms after first
    //third arrives 400ms after second
    .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .expectNext("third")//after sample period last received element should be received 
    .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: Check into `retryWhen` or `retry`. I've seen samples that sound very similar to this in various tutorials/examples on the same.

Answer (score 2):

By turning the source flux `myFlux` into a hot flux, you can easily achieve this:

```
Flux<T> myFlux;
Flux<T> sharedFlux = myFlux.publish().refCount(2);

Flux<T> first = sharedFlux.take(1);
Flux<T> sampledRest = sharedFlux.skip(1).sample(Duration.ofMillis(whatever));

return Flux.merge(first, sampledRest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it with `Flux#sample(org.reactivestreams.Publisher<U>)` method.

```
yourFlux.take(1)
        .mergeWith(yourFlux.sample(Flux.interval(yourInterval)
                .delaySubscription(yourFlux.take(1))))
```

Comment: it doesnt really solve my problem as it doesn't work if first element arrives after first element of Flux.interval is triggered (which is 99% of time)

Comment: note that this subscribes to `yourFlux` 3 times ! each subscription could trigger data creation (eg. http request), which would defeat the logic. that logic only works on "hot" flux... share and store the original flux to make it work: `Flux<T> shared = myFlux.publish.refCount(2);`